# Update state when the StickyHeader sticks on top [flutter]

Tags: flutter

I'm using sticky_headers package to create a sticky header in my vertical list view. When the header sticks to the top, I want to set the app bar elevation to 0. I tried setting the state on the callback argument but it threw an error. Can someone please let me know how I update the state when the header reaches the top?

**Error**
[image]

Comment: sticky_headers package: https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

Comment: For each heading use AppBar and write your heading text in title parameter, from this way you will achieve same functionality without using any package.